# SQL Server Log - Souce (SPID)

Tags: sql-server, logging, spid

In checking Log File Viewer for noteworthy events I came across a log that I wanted to investigate.

Let's say the log notes the Source as SPID1234

My question:
Is this SPID tied to the actual connection that generated the log or is the SPID associated with the process that is writing this to the log?

Comment: For more info about tracking what a specific SPID is doing I found this support page to be extremely helpful.
https://support.na.sage.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=26352&sliceId=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario, the SPID1234, which means the session that is running this command has ID of 1234.

from [here](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/spid-what-is-it)

> A SPID in SQL Server is a Server Process ID. These process ID’s are
>   essentially sessions in SQL Server. Everytime an application connects
>   to SQL Server, a new connection (or SPID) is created. This connection
>   has a defined scope and memory space and cannot interact with other
>   SPIDs. The term SPID is synonymous with Connection, or Session.

Answer (score 0):

SPID in Transaction Log - is ID of the process which originated the transaction, which was written into Transaction Log